# Vote up and posting hybrid answers

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

Since I only have 1 point so far, I cannot upvote any of the answers; none-the-less, I have made hybrid versions of dozens of answers from this site over the years.

It would have been nice to contribute my working hybrid versions of many of those answers, and given an upvote for the answers that my solutions were based on. And I believe in most cases, my hybrids of those answers are boiled down, standardized, and easier to read and use by the community; basically, I'm not inventing, just taking something and making it better.

Comment: So... what exactly is your question? You just want us to give you reputation so you can vote?

Comment: Hopefully by 'hybrid', you don't mean plagiarized.

Comment: Just make sure that if your work is derived from the work of others, that you cite the source.  If it's another SO answer, link to that answer so that others can give credit where due to the source, and determine which portion of the content is uniquely yours.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend simply posting your own answers to new/unanswered questions, in your own words.

People may not appreciate your efforts as much as you think they might; they might see it as mass plagiarism.

It depends how you do it. But to know how to do it properly, you will really need to have plenty of experience posting your own content.

So, dive in and put that knowledge to work with your own answers!